# Nesting Model Reports + Search Results

Tags: enterprise-architect

Seem like I'm not the first to investigate this. But not despairing yet :-)

The target state I'd like to reach is:

- A recursion through Packages, where some of the nested Sub-Packages are glorified Linked Documents, and some are Grids rendering Search Results.

I like that Model Documents provide Search Tag values -- but I can't seem to nest the grids where I want them to show up.

#### Approach 1: Nested Model Documents

If I could nest `Model Document` elements, with their Search/Search Term tags, I would be sorted. I could have

- Context:Package

  - Introduction:Package <- just renders a Linked Document attached to it
  - Systems Affected:Package <- just renders a Linked Document attached to it

    - Systems Affected:Model Document <- renders the results of a canned Search.

But EA appears to be designed to ignore the Model Document element.

#### Approach 2: SQL backed Template Fragment

I like the Model Document as it has Search/Search Term + all the Inclusion/Exclusion configuration options. But if I had to give that part up I am thinking of emulating as much as I can via SQL or script.

First attempt - using SQL and a nested set of Packages such as:

- Context:Package

  - Introduction:Package <- just renders a Linked Document attached to it
  - Systems Affected:Package <- just renders a Linked Document attached to it

    - Systems Affected:Package<> <- renders the results of a SQL Search.

If the template uses a TemplateSelector it can spot the Package with a wellknown stereotype, and invoke a Template that is backed by SQL.

The SQL uses the Package's Keywords as the source of the Element type to search for.

```
SELECT 
o.ea_guid AS [CLASSGUID], 
o.Object_Type AS [CLASSTYPE],
o.PDATA5 AS [KEYWORDS],
o.Object_Type AS [Type],
o.Stereotype AS [Stereotype],
*
FROM t_object as O 
WHERE O.Object_Type IN 
   (SELECT PDATA5 FROM t_object AS S where S.Object_ID = #OBJECTID#)
```

It works...barely.It's a bit hacky.

Searching off of Element Type is not going to be sufficient for production documents.

#### Approach 3: Script backed Template Fragment

If I can get a script running I suspect that I could leverage functionality that is already in the system.

- Context:Package

  - Introduction:Package <- just renders a Linked Document attached to it
  - Systems Affected:Package <- just renders a Linked Document attached to it

    - Systems Affected:Package<> <- renders the results of a canned Search.

If the template uses a TemplateSelector it can spot the Package with a wellknown stereotype, and invoke a Template that is backed by a script.

The script I'm trying is:

```
var x = Repository.GetElementsByQuery("POC.Req", "Device");
return x;
```

But the report remains blank of those elements I need for the table.

Q: Does the returned Collection need transformation before it can be used?

#### Approach 4

I've heard that there is an approach to Render Document sections as PDF, and link to them as Linked Documents... Sounds Convoluted. Sounds like a wrong/magic  approach.

#### Approach 5

Any other suggestions?

Thanks for the help.

### Addendum

Just got approach 3 to work by converting the script results to xml before handing it back

The template's script now looks like

```
-- first pass ...I'll work on passing the ObjectId in a bit in order to get fancier.
ExecuteSearch("Simple", "Device")
```

and it invokes a script saved somewhere else as

```
!INC Local Scripts.EAConstants-JScript

/*
 * Script Name: 
 * Author: 
 * Purpose: 
 * Date: 
 */

function main()
{
    return ExecuteSearch("Simple", "Device");
}

function ExecuteSearch(searchName, searchParam){
    var x = Repository.GetElementsByQuery(searchName, searchParam);
    //return x;
    var xmlDOC = CreateReport(x);
    var s = xmlDOC.xml;
    Session.Output(s);
    return s;
}

function CreateReport(entityCollection){
    var xmlDOC = CreateXmlDOC();
    var xmlRoot = AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"EADATA");
    var xmlDataSet = AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"Dataset_0",xmlRoot);
    var xmlData = AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"Data",xmlDataSet);

    for(var i = 0;i<entityCollection.Count();i++){
        var entity = entityCollection.GetAt(i);

        var xmlRow = AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"Row",xmlData);

        //AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"CLASSTYPE",xmlRow).Text = entity.Type;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"Guid",xmlRow).text = entity.ElementGUID;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"CLASSTYPE",xmlRow).text = entity.Type;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"CLASSGUID",xmlRow).text = entity.ElementGUID;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"Type",xmlRow).text = entity.Type;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"Stereotype",xmlRow).text = entity.Stereotype;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"Name",xmlRow).text = entity.Name;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"Object",xmlRow).text = entity.Name;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"Id",xmlRow).text = entity.ElementID;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"Scope",xmlRow).text = entity.Scope;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"Phase",xmlRow).text = entity.Phase;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"Status",xmlRow).text = entity.Status;
        var noteElement = AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"Notes",xmlRow);//.text = entity.Notes;

        noteElement.appendChild(xmlDOC.createCDATASection(entity.Notes));
        AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"Keywords",xmlRow).text = entity.PDATA5;

        }

    return xmlDOC;
}

function CreateXmlDOC()
{
    var xmlDOM;
    try
    {
           xmlDOM = new ActiveXObject( "MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0" );
    }
    catch(e)
    {
           xmlDOM = new ActiveXObject( "MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0" );
    }

    xmlDOM.createProcessingInstruction("xml","version=\"1.0\"");
    xmlDOM.validateOnParse = false;
    xmlDOM.async = false;

    return xmlDOM;
}

function AppendXmlChild(xmlDOM, xmlElementName, xmlParent, isCDATA){
    if (!xmlParent){xmlParent = xmlDOM;}

    var child = xmlDOM.createElement(xmlElementName);
    xmlParent.appendChild(child);
    return child;
}


main();
```

Comment: Just got approach 3 to work:

Comment: Did it by converting the results to xml

Comment: You can add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: And when you do, please add that, unless you're constructing the XML strings by hand, this solution requires an XML library (typically Microsoft's MSXML), which is not included in the EA installation.

Answer (score 0):

The script I used in the end is as follows. It now correctly investigates the element's tags for clues as how to proceed.

Hope it helps others.

```
!INC Local Scripts.EAConstants-JScript

/*
 * Script Name: 
 * Author: 
 * Purpose: 
 * Date: 
 */

 //Only used for development
function devTest()
{
    //With Child elements: {2255D8C8-F1BB-4069-BDAF-8B303D108C62}
    //With SearchName: {919252E0-BDEB-4f26-A39F-C0E74382952A}
    //With PackageGUID: {8543ED3B-EC39-4bf0-92C2-FD49A00C376B}

    Session.Output ("DEVTEST");
    var package = Repository.GetPackageByGuid("{8543ED3B-EC39-4bf0-92C2-FD49A00C376B}");

    Session.Output("Package Name:" + package.Name);
    Session.Output("Package Guid:" + package.PackageGUID);
    Session.Output("Package Id:" + package.PackageID);
    Session.Output("Package ElementId:" + package.Element.ElementID);
    //Session.Output("Package Element Id:" + package.Element.ElementID);


    //Use the Element associate to the Package, not the Package ID itself.
    var packageElementId = package.Element.ElementID; //NOT: package.PackageID;

    var xmlDoc=ExecuteSearch(packageElementId);
    try {
        Session.Output(xmlDoc.xml);
    }catch (e){
        Session.Output(e.message);
    }

}



//Extracts from a given Package it's SearchName/SearchValue tags
//in order to do a search that mimicks a ModelDocument's way of 
//generating a report.
function ExecuteSearch(elementId){
    //Validation
    if (!elementId){
        Session.Output("Exiting: No elementId received.");
        return;
    }   

    var packageElement = Repository.GetElementByID(elementId);
    if (!packageElement){
        Session.Output("Exiting: No package with given elementId: " + elementId);
        return;
    }

    try {
        var xmlDOC = ExecuteSearch2(packageElement);
        var xml = xmlDOC.xml;
        return xml;
    }catch (e){
        Session.Output("ERROR: " + e.message);
    }
    return null;
}

function ExecuteSearch2(packageElement){

    //Session.Output(packageElement.ElementGUID + ": '" + packageElement.Name +  "' invoking ExecuteSearch(" + packageElement.ElementID  + ")");
    //Session.Output("Attribute 'Test': " + GetElementTaggedValue(packageElement,'Test'));

    //Precendence is to search 
    //* Direct children,
    //* by Package, recursively, 
    //* Package, single
    //* Package

    //First dibs: does this package have any direct elements?

    //Get back to the package that is related to the Element before you count Elements:
    var package = Repository.GetPackageByGuid(packageElement.ElementGUID);
    var elementCollection = package.Elements;
    if (elementCollection.Count()){
        Session.Output("Package [" + packageElement.ElementGUID + "] has child Elements:"+ elementCollection.Count());
        return CreateReportDoc(elementCollection);
    }

    //If package had no children, look at Attributes for reference to other package.
    //At present, can't find an easy way to determine package Id from the EA GUI, so 
    //using the Guid.
    var searchPackageGuid = GetElementTaggedValue(packageElement,'SearchPackageGUID');
    if (!searchPackageGuid){
        searchPackageGuid = GetElementTaggedValue(packageElement,'SearchPackageGuid');
    }
    if (searchPackageGuid){
        //Session.Output("Package [" + packageElement.ElementGUID + "] has SearchPackageGuid:"+ searchPackageGuid);
        return ExecuteSearchByPackageGuid(searchPackageGuid);
    }

//  //If I ever find a way to get a packageId:
    var searchPackageId =  GetElementTaggedValue(packageElement,'SearchPackageId');
    if (searchPackageId){
        //Session.Output("Package [" + packageElement.ElementGUID + "] has SearchPackageId:"+ searchPackageId);
        return ExecuteSearchByPackageId(searchPackageId);
    }

//  //If searching by SQL:
    var searchSQL =  GetElementTaggedValue(packageElement,'SearchSQL');
    if (searchSQL){
        Session.Output("Package [" + packageElement.ElementGUID + "] has SearchSQL:"+ searchSQL);
        return ExecuteSearchBySQL(searchSQL);
    }

    //Not pointing to a package, so maybe pointing to a canned search:
    var searchName =  GetElementTaggedValue(packageElement,'SearchName');
    if (!searchName){
        //Session.Output("No SearchName");
        return;
    }

    var searchValue = GetElementTaggedValue(packageElement,'SearchValue');
    //Session.Output("Package [" + packageElement.ElementGUID + "] has SearchName/Value:"+ searchName + "/" + searchValue);
    return ExecuteSearchBySearchName(searchName, searchValue);
}


//Mimicks functionality of a ModelDocument that searches by canned SearchName/SearchValue.
function ExecuteSearchBySearchName(searchName, searchValue){
    var elementCollection = Repository.GetElementsByQuery(searchName, searchValue);
    //return x;
    return CreateReportDoc(elementCollection);
}

function ExecuteSearchByPackageGuid(packageGuid){
    var package = Repository.GetPackageByGuid(packageGuid);
    return ExecuteSearch2(package.Element);
}


function ExecuteSearchBySQL(searchSQL){
    var elementCollection = Repository.GetElementSet(searchSQL, 2); 
}


function HOLD_ExecuteSearchBySet(idList){
    var elementCollection = Repository.GetElementsSet(idList);
    //return x;
    return CreateReportDoc(elementCollection);
}

//Iterate through the elements and convert to an Xml Document
//suitable for use by a Script backed Template:
function CreateReportDoc(elementCollection){
    var xmlDOC = CreateXmlDOC();
    var xmlData = CreateXmlReport(xmlDOC);

    for(var i = 0;i<elementCollection.Count();i++){
        //For each Element, create a new row:
        var xmlRow = AppendXmlChild(xmlData,"Row");
        //And embed the specific element:
        var element = elementCollection.GetAt(i);
        CreateReportRow(xmlRow, element);
    }

    return xmlDOC;
}

function CreateReportRow(xmlRow, element){
        //And attach child property elements. 
        //For hairy ones, add them as a CDATA.
        //AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"CLASSTYPE",xmlRow).Text = element.Type;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Guid").text = element.ElementGUID;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"CLASSTYPE").text = element.Type;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"CLASSGUID").text = element.ElementGUID;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Type").text = element.Type;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Stereotype").text = element.Stereotype;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Name").text = element.Name;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Object").text = element.Name;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Id").text = element.ElementID;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Scope").text = element.Scope;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Phase").text = element.Phase;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Status").text = element.Status;
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Keywords").text = element.PDATA5;
        //Notes need wrapping as CDATA
        var noteElement = AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Notes");//.text = entity.Notes;
        noteElement.appendChild(xmlRow.ownerDocument.createCDATASection(element.Notes));
        //Now get tags:
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Tags.ID").text = GetElementTaggedValue(element,"ID");
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Tags.Type").text = GetElementTaggedValue(element,"Type");
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Tags.Category").text = GetElementTaggedValue(element,"Category");
        AppendXmlChild(xmlRow,"Tags.Traceability").text = GetElementTaggedValue(element,"Traceability");

        return xmlRow;
}

//helper function to create an empty xml document 
function CreateXmlDOC()
{
    var xmlDOM;
    try
    {
           xmlDOM = new ActiveXObject( "MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0" );
    }
    catch(e)
    {
           xmlDOM = new ActiveXObject( "MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0" );
    }

    xmlDOM.createProcessingInstruction("xml","version=\"1.0\"");
    xmlDOM.validateOnParse = false;
    xmlDOM.async = false;

    return xmlDOM;
}

//helper function to create the beginning of an xml document 
//suitable to render the results of a search:
function CreateXmlReport(xmlDOC){
    var xmlRoot = AppendXmlChild(xmlDOC,"EADATA");
    var xmlDataSet = AppendXmlChild(xmlRoot,"Dataset_0");
    var xmlData = AppendXmlChild(xmlDataSet,"Data");

    return xmlData;
}

//helper function to attach a new child xml element to a parent xml element
function AppendXmlChild(xmlParent, xmlElementName, isCDATA){
    var xmlDocument = xmlParent.ownerDocument;
    if (!xmlDocument){xmlDocument = xmlParent}
    var child = xmlDocument.createElement(xmlElementName);
    xmlParent.appendChild(child);
    return child;
}

//Gets an Element's tag. Eats exception if Tag does not exist.
function GetElementTaggedValue(element, tagName){
    var tag;
    try {
        tag = element.TaggedValues.GetByName(tagName);
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
    if (!tag){return;}
    var result = tag.Value;
    return result;
}


function ConvertPackageIdToBranchId(packageId){
    var package = Repository.GetPackageByID(objectId);
    if (!package){return;}

    var packages = [package];
    packages.concat(ConvertPackageToBranch(package));

    var result=[];
    for(var i=0;i<packages.length;i++){
        result.push(packages[i].PackageID);
    }
    return result;
}
function ConvertPackageToBranch(package){
    var result = [];

    for (var i=0;i<package.Packages.Count();i++){
        var childPackage = package.Packages.GetAt(i);
        result.push(childPackage);
        result.concat(ConvertPackageToBranch(childPackage));
    }
    return result;
}


//devTest();
```